# I want to run tanstack react query from outside of the component since I cannot use useQuery there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend, react-query

```
const getSurvey = useQuery(["survey"], () =>
    getSurveyData({
      page: 1,
      userLangCode: langCode,
      sortColumnName: "Date",
      sortColumnOrder: "DESC",
      country,
      ip,
    })
  );
```

I am trying to run the query after a certain event takes place but it gets called as soon as the component loads and give me undesirable results though after a while when component gets updated, it just works fine . Since I cannot be bounded in side a function. I need a method where I can use it from ouside the component vut the problem is I cannot use useQuery from outside.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell the query to start disabled and then manually fetch the data later with `refetch`:

```
function SuperAwesomeComponent() {
  const getSurvey = useQuery(["survey"], () =>
    getSurveyData({
      page: 1,
      userLangCode: langCode,
      sortColumnName: "Date",
      sortColumnOrder: "DESC",
      country,
      ip,
    }), {
      enabled: false
    }
  );

  const someEventHandler = () => {
    getSurvey.refetch();
  }
```

You can set enabled to the value of a prop or state variable to automatically run the query when a condition becomes true

See: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/dependent-queries

Answer (score 1):

Answer from coagmano is the one - just make sure you eventually call

`getSurvey.refetch();` instead of `getSurvey.refresh();`